# Modern problems in philosophy?

Tags: modernism

I cant imagine, what philosophers do in 21 centuary. My question is if is any hot topic in philosophy in these days?

Ps. i am so sorry if this tag is not right to my topic, but dont know which is the right one.

Comment: - Causality and chance

Comment: please can u get me more details ? For me this is only pair of two words with and between.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Causality, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminism#Philosophy

Comment: All scientific laws is phrased as something is caused by this. The conclusion is that universe can be determinated every time, but is not look like it. Quantum mechanics is good example of this. Philosophers are trying to solve this paradox. But main point is, in determinated universe cant be such a thing like soul and liberty. Am i right guys?

Comment: Nice chat with you guys. I thought i can star a discussion about this but i was wrog.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Philosophy SE. Please visit our [Help Center](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/help) to see what questions we answer and how to ask. Broad and vague questions like yours are off-topic on this site, they are best addressed by reading encyclopedia articles, e.g. [Wikipedia's Contemporary Philosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contemporary_philosophy).

Comment: I don't know how much sense it makes to talk of hot topics. However if I would have to name one then I would say consciousness is certainly a major topic in the 21st century that gets tackled from multiple different sides.

Comment: Please do feel free to clarify this question further so that it’s not quite so overlapping with that other one—  (This is definitely an interesting line of questioning!)

Comment: I want to start my own personal philosophical way and just was curious about  it. Thank you very much guys, and i am terribly sorry that my question is a bit of topic, but i thought that the rules wasnt so strict.

Comment: Something that is related to consciousness are (artificial) neural networks.

Comment: Algorithms and Robot Ethics ("Isaac Asimov").

Comment: Ethics related to primates and animals with highly developed social behavior.

Comment: @L.Dodo: I would read the other answers, but the comments here are 21st century problems for philosophy.

Comment: The particle-wave "duality"

Comment: The problems are the same as ever. Nothing has changed. I'm not sure why you would think they have. Every major philosophical problem faced by Plato remains one today in his academy.

Comment: @PeterJ: Neural networks, algorithms, and the particle wave duality weren't Plato's problems, duh'.

Comment: @jjack - The first two are not philosophical problems . The last is one in my opinion but most physicists would call it a scientific problem. I'd say that the problem of space and time subsumes the particle-wave duality so it is not really new, but I'd accept it as new. In this case there are more problems in philosophy than in Plato's day. I suppose this is a sort of  progress.

Comment: @jjack: What makes a philosophical problem? Is ethics off limits? When I think of philosophy, I don't mean "history of philosophy" but the actual practice. The space and time problem seems to have been solved by the relativistic 4D-spacetime.